# How to automatically categorize documents when indexing them in Apache Solr?

Tags: indexing, solr

I have a large mysql database and already configured solr search environment.
But I want to automatically categorize them when indexing data.
If you have experience in that phase, please help me!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how and what to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please also show what have you tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Categorize how? Using what criteria? Certain software? What have you tried? You'll have to expand your question with actual useful information.